# keyboard modifications reset on suspend, modifying xinitrc, xsession, xprofile, and profile unsuccessful

Tags: suspend, keyboard-layout

In my setup, I include
`setxkbmap dvorak -option ctrl:nocaps`
in:

- .xinitrc
- .xsession
- .xprofile

- .profile

But if I close my laptop lid and re-open, my keyboard remains in dvorak, but the capslock key returns to capslock. What else should I change?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What I write here is a work around and not a true solution.

There are two possible cases on what your system does when you close the lid:

1. Suspend
2. Lock screen / screensaver

**Case 1:**

If your system suspends when you close the lid, you can create a script at this location: `/usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/`. Scripts located here are run before the system suspends and after it resumes. So, create the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 2> /tmp/resume_test_err.txt
if [ "${1}" = "post" ]; then
  # Do the thing you want after resuming here
  echo "resuming" >> /tmp/resume_test.txt # just for testing
  /usr/bin/setxkbmap dvorak -option ctrl:nocaps
fi
```

You will need to use super user permissions (`sudo`) to create a script in this directory. After, you can set this file to executable:

```
sudo chmod +x scriptname
```

where `scriptname` is the file name containing that script.

You can test the script using

```
./scriptname post
```

You can remove or comment the `echo` statement once you have verified that the script is working. Depending on whether script works or not, you should find an output file `resume_test.txt` or `resume_test_err.txt` in the directory `/tmp/`.

If everything goes okay until here, the script should work when you resume your system next time, the `setxkbmap` command should get executed.

---

**Case 2:**

If your system is set to screen lock on lid close, then create the following script in any appropriate directory, then set the script to executable using `chmod +x scriptname`.

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" |
  while read x; do
    case "$x" in 
      *"boolean false"*) /usr/bin/setxkbmap dvorak -option ctrl:nocaps;;  
    esac
  done
```

Then, you can launch the script at system start (you can do this by adding the script to Startup applications of Ubuntu).

If your system runs Ubuntu with gnome desktop, this should work fine.
But for other distributions and desktop environments, you might have to replace `org.gnome.ScreenSaver` with an appropriate statement. For e.g., on Linux mint cinnamon, I had to use `org.cinnamon.ScreenSaver`. But on Ubuntu systems with gnome desktop environment, no change should be required.

This answer is based on information from following posts

1. [Running scripts before and after suspend with systemd](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2016/05/11/running-scripts-before-and-after-suspend-with-systemd/)
2. [How to run a script on screen lock/unlock?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/how-to-run-a-script-on-screen-lock-unlock)

Comment: @cryptograthor let me know if the answer helps or not